# Typescript Interfaces - Two possible key names for one property

Tags: typescript

I have this interface, I was curious if there is a possible way to specify potential names that the key value could be. But I still get reference errors saying "bottom" isn't apart of `IStyles`. I am fairly new to using typescript, and when searching through stackoverflow, none of the other answers regarding what I was looking for jumped out at my immediately as the answer so I apologize if this is already somewhere and I have overlooked it.

I am looking to achieve something like this for a Svelte project I am working on as these key-names are obviously css names, so its imperative that I use the actually naming.

```js
interface IStyles
    {
        position?: string;
        [top | bottom] ?: string | number;
        margin?: string | number;
        padding?: string | number;
        background?: string | Colors;
    }
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, is there a reason to redeclare types for CSS? There are many options readily available for this as far as I know.

Comment: @Etheryte I made a simple component in Svelte with a styles prop that I wanted to pass a set of specific styles to control its positioning, size, and color. Svelte has no way to target components with css- aside from passing values through props and creating in-line styles. At least from what I have found. 

Worst case scenario, the answer to my question is no its not possible and I just have extra lines in my interface for bottom. 

Edit: Also like I said I am new with typescript, like I didn't know typescript had typings for CSS already... so let me look into that.. Haha

Comment: Is your goal to have interface with either `top` or `bottom` key, but not both?

Comment: @tymzap My goal was it could be either or, but nothing else. But I see what you're getting at. With that point made I am better off just including both.

Comment: "either or, but nothing else" What does that mean, exactly?  Does that mean *exclusive or*?  If so then you need a union type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyX1Km).  If you mean *inclusive or* then you can just put both keys in the one interface like [this](https://tsplay.dev/W4x0KW).  And if don't mean any of those (not sure what "but nothing else" should imply), can you spell it out?

Comment: I meant inclusive, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to do it all in one line. But thank you for both of those examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you wanted that `top` and `bottom` properties are exclusive.

This is possible in TypeScript, but only with "type" and not with "interface", but most often both can be used very similar. So maybe this works for you:

```
type TopOrBottom = { top?: string | number; bottom?: undefined } | { top?: undefined; bottom?: string | number }

type IStyles = TopOrBottom & {
    position?: string;
    margin?: string | number;
    padding?: string | number;
    background?: string;
};

const validTop: IStyles = { top: 123 };
const validBottom: IStyles = { bottom: '12px' };
const invalid: IStyles = { bottom: '12px', top: 12 }; // TS error
```

See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9mA8gJwEJ2MOBbKBeKAbyizAH4AuKAZ2GQEsA7AcygB8pGBXbAIwmQBuKLwxZslKF0YATCADMmEGVAC+7IiQSTpcxY2XDRmHJNoMWG7nwFqAUHdCQoASQDKoADYRq+WAhR0E1wAMiI7KEioMDhqemB6OEYzOiZmQQio7ABDZGYmFItWDmt+IUzIsGyZGTTCtKseMoyokWyAYwBrZmQ4XXqWDNUMu3ak2igAN2zPehl4MCp3Lx8-YlIqAEYAJgBmNQyxxgnp2Zkg8SWPEG9fAmJjS6gAch2wAA9ng9Hx4CgmU5zK4rO6aR44KivbYfZ4AGi0iygO2+QA)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare properties like that.

One thing that you can do is to group your common keys in an object and then use [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to create more complex types. Something similar to this:

```
const Common = {
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
};

type IStyles = {
  position?: string;
  margin?: string | number;
  padding?: string | number;
  background?: string | Colors;
} & {  
  [Prop in keyof typeof Common]: string | number;
}

let a: IStyles = {
}
```